# Using in 'category_name' in '$query->set();'?

Tags: categories, wp-query, wp-admin, query, terms

Here's the function I have in my theme's functions.php:

```
function better_editions( $query ) {

    // Categories act as 'Editions' on my site

    $get_edition = get_query_var( 'category_name' );
    if( $get_edition !== '' ) {
        $edition = get_term_by( 'slug', $get_edition, 'category' );
        if( $edition && !is_wp_error( $edition ) ) {
            $edition = $get_edition;
        }
    }

    if ( $query->is_category() && isset($edition) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
        $query->set( 'category_name', $edition.', intl' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'better_editions' );
```

I use the function to display posts that belong to 'International (intl)' category under all categories (in all category archives, category posts listings, etc).

As I learnt, in order to define multiple categories with `category_name` in `$query->set();`, this is the only way, unless I am wrong:

```
$query->set( 'category_name', 'category1, category2' );
```

Which is what I am doing, as shown in the function far above.

The problem is, with the function in place, I get this error:

> **Notice:** Array to string conversion in **/var/www/wp.dev/public/wp-admin/edit.php** on line **225**

**The error is only visible** with `debug` turned on, and only on category-specific "All Posts" page. For example...

```
http://wp.dev/wp-admin/edit.php?category_name=intl
```

...the above link lists all posts under "International (intl)" category in wp-admin.

What am I doing wrong in the function? How do I fix this?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use `!is_admin()` because I want the function to apply to wp-admin as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to duplicate the problem, but [the `Notice` references this line](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/edit.php#L225):

```
add_screen_option( 'per_page', array( 'label' => $title, 'default' => 20, 'option' => 'edit_' . $post_type . '_per_page' ) );
```

And that makes me think that you should be passing a post type in your `GET` string.

```
http://wp.dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=post&category_name=intl
```

Just a guess as I can't duplicate the issue. If that doesn't move you forward I will delete the answer :)

Comment: Whoa! That tip did it! It's that I am setting the post type on this line: `$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );`. Removing it from the function resolved the problem, while retaining all functionality. Thank you very much! If possible, please edit your answer to make note of this.

Comment: On my phone, I'll update later. Glad it helped.